# 'h1:nth-child(5)' selects 3rd and not 5th child

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css-selectors

To the best of my knowledge these are all the H1 tags in index.html.

```
<h1 class='header'>Hello, world (1)</h1>
<h1 class='header'>Hello, world (2)</h1>
<h1 class='header'>Hello, world (3)</h1>
<h1 class='header'>Hello, world (4)</h1>
<h1 class='header'>Hello, world (5)</h1>
<h1 class='header'>Hello, world (6)</h1>

<h1 class='header' id='header-3'>Hello, world (Header 3)(1)</h1>
<h1 class='header' id='header-3'>Hello, world (Header 3)(2)</h1>
```

I checked the console logs and they implied I had 8 H1 elements.

```
 var $header = $(".header")        
 console.log("header length")
 console.log($header.length)
```

When I wrote this  `$('h1:nth-child(5)').text("Ironman")` I expected it to adjust the 5th H1 element. Whereas it actually adjusts the 4th.

When I wrote this `$('h1:nth-child(4)').text("Thanos")` I expected it to adjust the 4th element. Whereas it actually adjusts the 3rd.

According to w3schools (https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_nthchild.asp) the first element has the index number 1.

Could anyone provide clarification as to what is going on?

**Update**

Here is all my code (apologies for the messy way it pasted into StackOverflow).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

     <style>
    /*body {
      background-color: red;
    }*/
    h1 {
      color: green;
    }

    #header-3 {

    }
    .description {
      width: 250px;
      height: 300px;
    }
  </style>


  </head>
  <body>
```

`<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js'></script>`

```
    <h1 class='header' id='header-3'>Hello, world (Header 3)(1)</h1>
    <h1 class='header' id='header-3'>Hello, world (Header 3)(2)</h1>
   

 
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){

    
        var $header = $(".header")        
        console.log("header length")
        console.log($header.length)
        

        setTimeout(function(){
            $('body').css("background-color", "blue")
            $('h1').css("color", "purple")
            $('h1').text("Batman")
            $('h1:nth-child(5)').text("Ironman")
            $('#header-3').text("Captain America")
            $(".header").css("background-color", "green").css("padding", "30px")
        }, 6500) // in ms
     

        setTimeout(function(){
            $('body').css("background-color", "yellow")
            $('h1').css("color", "purple")
            $('h1:nth-child(1)').text("Wolverine")
            $('h1:nth-child(2)').text("Magneto")
            $('h1:nth-child(4)').text("Thanos")
            $(".header").css("background-color", "green").css("padding", "30px")
        }, 8500) // in ms
      
 })

   </script>




    <p class='description'>Another Paragraph</p>
    <p class='description'>It turns out self-driving cars aren’t dissimilar from self-driving humans: 
Today, a generation removed from the seminal 2004 Darpa challenge in which the 

“The hype got ahead of the reality, but honestly, it’s gone way faster than I would have ever believed,” says 

automaker still hopes to fulfill that vision by 2021.

Nuro, which rounded up $1 billion from SoftBank, said the cash being deposited in the self-driving landscape has provided a critical slug of optimism. “It doesn’t change our plan or our mission,

</p>




 
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){


        var $description = $(".description")
  

       
        console.log($description.css("height"))
       
        console.log($description.height())


       
       
      
 })

   </script>



   <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!--  Popper.js first, then Bootstrap JS -->

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Update 2**

Thank you j08691 for your answer.

Comment: Unable to re-create this issue. Your code does work well. https://jsfiddle.net/Lmwh12j7/

Comment: No repro here either. Post a [mcve] please. Also, IDs **must** be unique

Comment: In this case, your code is working properly. Because the first-child is script, not the H1. If you want to select always the third h1, then you need to do it differently. Thanks

Comment: Also know that you should in only rare cases have more than one h1 on a page, perhaps as the header of a section element. And I'd suggest using the of type pseudo though I haven't tested this in your case: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type

Comment: Hey Nathaneil

I was just doing a test exercise. Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with your example is in your implementation. As the docs for jQuery's [:nth-child](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) say (emphasis mine):

> The :nth-child(n) pseudo-class is easily confused with the .eq( n )
> call, even though the two can result in dramatically different matched
> elements. With :nth-child(n), **all children are counted, regardless of
> what they are**, and the specified element is selected only if it
> matches the selector attached to the pseudo-class.

In other words, `:nth-child` doesn't care what the `nth` element is, it counts everything, and in your example the script element is a child of the body, so it's being counted. If you move it to the end of the page, it works as you expect

```js
$('h1:nth-child(4)').text("Ironman");
```

```html
<h1 class='header'>Hello, world (1)</h1>
<h1 class='header'>Hello, world (2)</h1>
<h1 class='header'>Hello, world (3)</h1>
<h1 class='header'>Hello, world (4)</h1>
<h1 class='header'>Hello, world (5)</h1>
<h1 class='header'>Hello, world (6)</h1>

<h1 class='header' id='header-3'>Hello, world (Header 3)(1)</h1>
<h1 class='header'>Hello, world (Header 3)(2)</h1>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

One alternative that would do what you would expect and leave the script element as first is [:nth-of-type](https://api.jquery.com/nth-of-type-selector/):

```js
$('h1:nth-of-type(4)').text("Ironman");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class='header'>Hello, world (1)</h1>
<h1 class='header'>Hello, world (2)</h1>
<h1 class='header'>Hello, world (3)</h1>
<h1 class='header'>Hello, world (4)</h1>
<h1 class='header'>Hello, world (5)</h1>
<h1 class='header'>Hello, world (6)</h1>

<h1 class='header' id='header-3'>Hello, world (Header 3)(1)</h1>
<h1 class='header'>Hello, world (Header 3)(2)</h1>
```